# Задачка по программированию вложенных циклов

Tags: java

Помогите решить пожалуйста задачу по вложенным циклам. Никак не могу разобраться в условии. Как ее можно реализовать на java?

Дано натуральное число n (от 1 до 9).
Вывести n строк, в которых последующие значения строки линейно зависят от предыдущего значения, а первые элементы каждой строки линейно зависят от первого элементы в предыдущей строке.

Пример входных данных 1

1

Пример выходных данных 1

8

Пример входных данных 2

2

Пример выходных данных 2

8 18

12 26

Пример входных данных 3

3

Пример выходных данных 3

8 18 38

12 26 54

16 34 70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понимаю, за что столько минусов сделали по данному вопросу. На мой взгляд тема довольно актуальная. Решение данной задачи затрагивает логическое мышление.

Вот алгоритм:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();

        Integer currentValueCol = 8;
        Integer indexMnosh = 10;

        for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {

            if (i > 0) {
                currentValueCol = currentValueCol + 4;
                indexMnosh = indexMnosh + 4;
            }
            Integer currentValueRow = null;

            for (int j=0; j < n; j++) {
                int resetValue = j > 0 ? currentValueRow + indexMnosh * j: currentValueCol;
                currentValueRow = resetValue;

                String value = j < n-1 ? currentValueRow + " ": currentValueRow.toString();
                System.out.print(value);
            }
            if (i < n-1) System.out.println();

        }

        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Столько минусов потому, что автор даже не попробовал сам что-то сделать, а просто вывалил задание, пусть ребята за него сделают